# Codeigniter + Nginx + php-fpm = 502 error

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

i’ve tried several configuration instructions and forum posts but nothing worked for me, I still get 502-bad gateway errors when I try to access my website.

```
$config[“index_page”] = “”;

...

$config[“uri_protocol”] = “REQUEST_URI”; // also tried AUTO
```

**My nginx configuration:**

```
server {
    server_name     dev.monitr.io;
    root            /home/monitr/web/dev/www/;
    include         /etc/sites/ci_vhost;
}
```

**/etc/sites/ci_vhost:**

```
index index.html index.php index.htm;

# set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
 expires max;
 log_not_found off;
}

location / {
 # Check if a file exists, or route it to index.php.
 try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
}

location @rewrites {
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
            break;
        }
    }

   location ~ \.php {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

kind regards, phillip

Comment: Check that your fastcgi is running: `sudo ps ax | grep php` and check existanceof /var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket

Comment: php-fpm is running but the socket doesnt exist. replaced it with fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; and now the gateway works, but i get 500-server error messages (http://dev.monitr.io)

Comment: When php fatal error happens fastcgi send 500 header to nginx. You can temporary replace your framework with single phpinfo script and check out your installation.

Comment: http://dev.monitr.io/ - here you can see the configuration

Comment: You don't have php5_mysql package installed. 99% sites on CI use mysql. Think, your's also. On debian do something like `apt-get install php5-mysql`. If 500 apperas again set in php.ini display_erros to true and error reporting to E_ALL. You should see php error and understand the problem. If not, set in php.ini `error_log = /absolute/path/to/logfile` and read it. Btw, look in `/var/log/php-fpm.log` (or smth like this). If there is no log for php-fpm, set it in /etc/php5/php-fpm.ini (or smth like this). Good luck!

Comment: Please, let me know, if your app runs and how did you fixed your problems.

Comment: I installed php5-mysql and mysql-server, imported the database and changed the database configuration in application/config/database.php. I also set error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors to true but I still can't see any errors in the php-fpm.log or in the browser (still getting 500-server error)

Comment: That is weird. May be, let's try to log php errors (set `error_log = /absolute/path/to/logfile` in php.ini). When I installed php-fpm I had problems with file permissions, but it was 403 error.

Comment: i've set the error_log file but I guess I have to restart php-fpm first? `service php5-fpm restart` or `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart` doesnt work neither

Comment: What do these commands output? Script not found? Maybe it has some other name: `ls -lah /etc/init.d/  | grep php`

Comment: in /etc/init.d/ there are no php related scripts, and `ps ax | grep php` shows that there is no php-fpm running?!

Comment: How did you installed all your stuff? I mean, always `apt-get` or something is compiled by hand?

Comment: php is compiled by hand – I followed this tutorial: http://interfacelab.com/nginx-php-fpm-apc-awesome/

Comment: This article is bad and old. `make`ing packages is a bad way. Even if you will start your php-fpm now, system will certanly let you down one day. And you won't be able to upgrade it. Now I'm going to write an "answer" with instruction of proper installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Follow instruction](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) to add dotdeb.org to you apt sources. Dotdeb.org has packages of modern nginx and php.

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get install nginx
3. configure nginx (your previous config is more or less ok, google "nginx php 5.3" manuals)
4. apt-get install php5-cli php5-common php5-suhosin //suhosin is good for security
5. apt-get install php5-fpm php5-cgi
6. /etc/init.d/nginx restart
7. /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
8. Try your phpinfo script
9. Install mysql, pear, etc. Don't forget about some opcode cacher - huge perfomance boost for CI.

Google "nginx php 5.3" for complete manuals, there are many. Wish you not to compile anything from sources :)

Comment: one little question: when I want to protect that domain with a htpasswd file, I put:
`auth_basic            "Restricted";
       auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd;`
into the location ~ \.php{} but nothing happens

Comment: Do you add `location  /  {
  auth_basic            "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd;
}` to you `/etc/nginx/nginx.config` (or smth), like in docs http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule

Comment: Never used this module, sorry. All I can suggest is this link from official wiki: http://kbeezie.com/view/protecting-folders-with-nginx/